# Android - TimePicker selecting the button and input field

Tags: android

I'm trying to modified the way TimePicker works as asked in my question here [Android - TimePicker minutes to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15)

To be able to do that I need to know if the + and - button was clicked and to disable the input field.

So can I target the elements in a TimePicker? (i.e the + and - button and the input field)?

Also is there anyway to determine if the + or the - button was clicked?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous date in a variable and figure out on event, if that was increased or decreased. This way you detect if the plus or minus was used.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the input field though? Tee

Comment: I don't know the answer for that question.