# How to customize a TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, timepicker

I want a timepickerDialog in my application, that can increase minute by 15 and also I want to get value of selected AM/PM.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue, see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15).

For the second, you should first set a listener:

```
OnTimeSetListener listener = new OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int hour, int minute) {
            //whatever you want to do with hour and minute
        }
};
```

Then display the `TimePickerDialog`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, listener, hour, minute, true);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Make habit of acccepting answers