# Set TimePickerDialog to use 15 minute intervals

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How do I set an Android `TimePickerDialog` to use 15 minute intervals?

I need to create the picker programmatically as shown below so solutions involving a timepicker in XML (such as here: [Android - TimePicker minutes to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15)) will not work.

```
new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), t, hour,minute, false).show();
```

The problem is that there appears to be no way to pass in a new function for `TimePicker .setOnTimeChangedListener()` when the time picker is created.

Is it possible to use the new TimePIckerDialog constructor and use 15 minute intervals?

Answer (score 2):

Override the onTimeChanged method

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, listener, 1, 1, true) {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            ...
        }
};

timePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: There is no method setOnTimeChangedListener for TimePickerDialog

Comment: I believe we need to override the OnTimeChangedListener, not the OnTimeSetListener.

Answer (score 2):

all relative answer need you to set an OnTimeChangedListener. My resolution is that you extends android TimePicker,and modify the constructor of it:

```
// minute
mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.minute);
mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue(3);
mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"0", "15", "30", "45"});
mMinuteSpinner.setOnLongPressUpdateInterval(100);
mMinuteSpinner.setFormatter(NumberPicker.getTwoDigitFormatter());
```

so you can have the interval you want.

Comment: is this work in 23 to 28? I want to show in Clock mode only.

Answer (score 0):

Gathering partial solutions from this and other posts, I believe the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19970113/530513) ticks all of the boxes for displaying a `TimePickerDialog` with a custom minute increment displayed in the `NumberPicker`.