# Android TimePicker custom minute step

Tags: android

The default Android Time Picker, have a step of 1 for minute. I want to change it to a step of 5 minutes. so by clicking on the "+" button, the time 09:20 become 09:25.

Is there an easy way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own TimePicker. I'm not sure if you can extend the existing TimePicker and handle the button events on your own. Here is more detailed answer for your question:

[Android - TimePicker minutes to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15)