# Android TimePicker at intervals for 5 minutes

Tags: java, android, timepicker

My problem is that I need to implement TimePicker at intervals for 5 minutes.

All the examples that I was looking for here

[Android - TimePicker minutes to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15)

and here

[How do i change the Android TimePicker minute intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187341/how-do-i-change-the-android-timepicker-minute-intervals)

for me does not work.

If I may, I would like to see a full working example.

This code works, but I do not know how to pass the time here to install, and do not know how to get the time

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.NumberPicker; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TimePicker pickStartTime;
    TextView textwiew;
    private int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 5;
    NumberPicker minutePicker;
    List<String> displayedValues;


    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    private int myHourS = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    private int myMinuteS = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    int nextMinute = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textwiew =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

        pickStartTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        pickStartTime.setIs24HourView(true);

        setTimePickerInterval(pickStartTime);
    }


    private void setTimePickerInterval(TimePicker timePicker) {
        try {
            Class<?> classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
            // Field timePickerField = classForid.getField("timePicker");

            Field field = classForid.getField("minute");
            minutePicker = (NumberPicker) timePicker
                    .findViewById(field.getInt(null));

            minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
            minutePicker.setMaxValue(11);
            displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            //  for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
            //      displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            //  }
            minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues
                    .toArray(new String[0]));
            minutePicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onClick (View v) {
      int   Minut = pickStartTime.getCurrentMinute();
        textwiew.setText(Minut);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do not know how to get the time

Using `OnTimeChangedListener`

```
pickStartTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
pickStartTime.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Log.d("Time", "You picked "
                + String.valueOf(view.getCurrentHour()) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(view.getCurrentMinute()));
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. Can you tell me how to set the current time?

Comment: setHour and setMinute... From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html)