# Time Picker with customized intervals in Android

Tags: java, android, timepicker, android-timepicker

Hi I am an absolute beginner in Android app development. I want to customize my time picker such that it shows 30 minute intervals only. Please guide me through step-by-step how I can do this. Otherwise, if you have a solution, could you please post the code here so I can figure it out on my own?

Comment: probably worth adding a language tag to your question

Comment: can you share more details like image or what customization's want to exactly.

Comment: I just need the time picker to only allow selecting 0 or 30 for the minutes

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214547/show-timepicker-with-minutes-intervals-in-android or this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187341/how-do-i-change-the-android-timepicker-minute-intervals