# Modify the next and previous times in a TimePickerDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, timepicker

I've successfully implemented a TimePickerDialog that [only allows the user to select a minute value that is an increment of 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15), e.g. 00, 15, 30, 45.  However, the "grayed out" next and previous times still show +/- 1 minute, which is unintuitive from a user perspective.  Is there any way to modify the next and previous times programatically?  I have searched through the related APIs and attempted to search the view tree in a debugger, but I cannot find a way to do so.

[image: an illustration of the unintuitive timepickerdialog]

To illustrate the problem, here is the TimePickerDialog with 7:30 PM selected.  When the user clicks 31, the TimePicker will actually select 7:45.  How can I update the gray "next" value to show 45 instead of 31?