# Default Time picker with minute 15 min difference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want to use Default timer with 15 min difference in android 6.0 and lollipop version. I already referred all the links but all solutions are old. Can any one suggest me to use time-picker with 15 min difference in clock min interval in android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini I already Referred but this all solution are old not for lollipop and marshmallow default time picker..

Comment: what the problem with these version

Comment: This solutions is not useful for these versions. Given solutions is not working for these versions..